# How to resolve local Artifacts in Maven 3?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-3

How do I resolve an artifact's path in the local repository in Maven 3?

In Maven 2 you could use [ArtifactResolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440224/how-can-i-download-maven-artifacts-within-a-plugin/1440241#1440241) to populate an Artifact object with the relevant information, but this class has been deprecated in Maven 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best replacement of `ArtifactFactory` (also deprecated with M3) is `RepositorySystem`. `createDependencyArtifact`,... operations are available.

Comment: One method that's missing from `RepositorySystem` is `createParentArtifact`, but internally it simply calls `createProjectArtifact`, so use that instead.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question:

```
/**
 * @component
 */
private ArtifactFactory artifactFactory;
/**
 * The local maven repository.
 *
 * @parameter expression="${localRepository}"
 * @required
 * @readonly
 */
private ArtifactRepository localRepository;
[...]
Artifact artifact = artifactFactory.createArtifactWithClassifier(groupId, artifactId, version, type, classifier);
artifact.setFile(new File(localRepository.getBasedir(), localRepository.pathOf(artifact)));
```

Comment: What about RepositorySystem and RepositorySystemSession?

Comment: You're right. RepositorySystem looks like a drop-in replacement for ArtifactRepository.

Comment: Bear in mind that you can continue to use ArtifactResolver if you need your plugin to be compatible with Maven 2.

Comment: Brett, how is it possible ? I have ald project created using maven-core-2.0.9 now I have migrate this plugin to maven3. So I use maven-core-3.0

Comment: Brett, how is it possible ? I have ald project created using maven-core-2.0.9 now I have migrate this plugin to maven3. So I use maven-core-3.0
But ArtifactResolver located in the 2.0.9 version only.